# How to update entire UI for the application according to user selection?

Tags: ios, ipad, user-interface, color-scheme

I have an application requirement where user chooses color & font for title, labels, textfields. Images for logo, etc.

Here is the brief scenario:

- Some screen which provides base application use
- Settings screen, where user can update UI: Here I have provided textfields where user can enter color schemes for all provided labels and image selection.
- For example, Line color, Line Shadow color, Font Color, Divider Color. User input will be R,G,B values (like, 123, 255, 89)

Once user save this configuration, entire application UI should be changed for all the viewControllers accordingly.

What would be the preferable way to achieve this?

I do already have all the IBoutlets for each and every label, textfields, imageviews. - Just FYI.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple, non-complicated way of getting this working is to store all these choices in NSUserDefaults - and have all the customisable controls draw themselves using the property settings there.

Comment: I have used sharedInstance for application scope. Can I store my sharedInstance object in NSUserDefaults and for next launch fetch values from that. Is this possible then how ?

Comment: You mean singletons.  DONT and I really mean DONT store anything in a singleton.  NSUserDefaults if the easiest way.  also, don't store the whole object, just store it's properties.

Comment: It works, thanks... 
The only thing was as i was having custom objects to save, i used NSCoding first then saved those to NSUserDefaults... 
Thanks